# noUiSlider get raw value

Tags: javascript, nouislider

I'm using noUiSlider and followed the tutorial how to create custom formatting:

```
noUiSlider.create(sliderFormat, {
start: [ 20 ],
step: 10,
range: {
    'min': [ 0 ],
    'max': [ 599 ]
},
format: {
  to: function ( value ) {
    return Math.round(value/60) + ':' + Math.round(value%60);
  },
  from: function ( value ) {
    return value;
  }
}
});
```

When I call

```
mySlider.get()
```

it returns a value like 1:10, which is the formatted value. I would like to get the raw value (like 70 in this example), how is that possible?

Comment: Do you want to get the raw value when someone is changing the slider?

Comment: if you don't want to get the formatted value, then why you are formatting it, If you don't format, myslider.get will return 70.

Comment: I reading the value as soon as the slider changes. I need to format it for the user experience so the slider shows a hours/minute value in the ui field.

Comment: if you want to get both the raw and formatted value, use 'update' function. You can format your value there.

Comment: maybe just format it back with the reverse code of how you formatted it?

Comment: Yes, but that would be a dirty solution, I was hoping the component supports something like the internal "raw" value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Vaibhav Kumar suggestet, I used the update function to read the raw value:

```
slider.noUiSlider.on('update', function(values,handle,unencoded){
   // unencoded contains the raw value
});
```